# ArcGIS scripting convert FeatureClass to Shapefile with user-defined shapefile name

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool

I am trying to convert a feature class inside a geodatabase to a shapefile at a location outside of the geodatabase. I am aware that I can use the function `arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToShapefile(Input_Features, Output_Folder)` to convert a feature class. However, I think this function doesn't allow the user to specify the name of the shapefile and the output shapefile has the same name as the input feature class.

I want to specify the name of the output shapefile because I want to use the shapefile later in my script. I know that an alternative is to just use the default shapefile path generated by `arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToShapefile`. This works for most situations. However, if there is a Shapefile in the `Output_Folder` with the same name (for example `output.shp`), this function will automatically rename the output Shapefile to `output_1.shp` and it is hard for me to keep track of which one is the one I created if there are multiple duplicates (many `output_x.shp` in the output folder) in the `Output_Folder` (rare scenario but still possible). Therefore, I want to specify my own pathname for the output shapefile. Does anyone know how to do this, maybe without using the `arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToShapefile` function?

Answer (score 2):

After some exploration I found that the function `arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(in_features, out_path, out_name, {where_clause}, {field_mapping}, {config_keyword})`

> https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm

If I specify a `out_path` that is a folder (but not a geodatabase), the file `out_name` will be saved as a `.shp`. This function solved my problem.